# brew services. Cant start service. get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, macos-big-sur, launchctl

running `brew services start mongodb-community` which yields:

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/<myUserName>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` exited with 5.
```

when I run `launchctl load -w /Users/<myUserName>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist`

yields

`Load failed: 5: Input/output error`

I recently upgraded macOs to BigSur 11.5.2.

Ive uninstall and reinstalled homebrew and xcode.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/kbko61/launchctl_broken/gpv2to1/

Didn't add this as an answer cuz it's not mine. This worked for me

Comment: Ive tried this and I still get the same error.  I wonder if I gave the correct inputs with the commands?  Brew services should just work, as its the official way MongoDB says to start the service.

Comment: Thank you @HarshKumar, this link saved my day!

Answer (score 153):

try this

`brew services restart <mongodb-community@4.4>`

Comment: Surprisingly, it works. Thanks Mari!

Comment: still same problem

Comment: This worked for me after migrating from Mac Intel to M1. Thanks!

Comment: it works but why

Comment: Works for me, so I just needed to be specific with the version number eh

Comment: Had a similar problem with httpd an i'm so surprised that this is working, but it is! thanks you man

Comment: It works I don't know why)

Comment: If you are here for `httpd` or `other port binding services`, please refer to @marcus.salinas' answer on this forum. File permissions and thus user starting your services may play a role here.

Comment: also worked for redis!

Comment: what on earth..........!!!!! :/ it works

Comment: Had the same issue with rabbitmq, this works. But why!? :)

Comment: still work in 2024, wtf is this black magic mate :))

Answer (score 54):

I saw this issue with MySQL and the solution was my current profile was not the owner of my homebrew folder.

I had to change it because I have a second profile set up for another work space, but they share the same homebrew path.

I would suggest anyone who sees this error try running

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

And then seeing if that will resolve it. Again I didn't have this issue with MongoDB, but I saw this exact error with MySQL when my profile didn't own the brew folder.

Comment: After exploring a few options, this seems a lixely fix for me. In the interim, I got postgresql running using `sudo brew servies start postgresql`

Comment: adding ```sudo``` before brew fixed it for me.

Comment: Machine restart was also needed

Comment: Some servers such as apache need be run as root to bind to the correct port. If you bind on a non-system protected port you may find better luck. My nginx server runs fine under my non-privileged user. `sudo` may in fact be the only way to start `httpd`. What's interesting is the seeming false positive errors you might get if you view `sudo brew services list` with and without `sudo`. This full feed was eye opening.

Comment: [It's worth linking why and how `apache` does this](https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_Apache_HTTP_Server_2.4_Benchmark_v2.0.0_Level_1.audit:3e40bb6b17d51e608448449f08a3b496) to understand security considerations.

Comment: thanks. I tried several ways but it doesnt work. this update work perfectly. thanks

Comment: I tried many other answers and only this one worked for me. I didn't restart the Mac to achieve it.

Comment: This seems to stop all the nonsense coming out of my terminal, thanks!

Comment: I run into the problem after I had to do a cold reboot of my Mac.
This helped me out. Otherwise I had to do a clean install of brew -> mysql.
Thanks

Answer (score 43):

I am able to run mongodb through homebrew.  I believe this solved my issue:

`launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist`

followed by

`launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist`

Comment: This fixed the problem I was having

Comment: This fixed it, without having to force version 4.4 - nice!

Comment: This works when the firewall is blocking the java server launched. Once you unload and load again, you'll see a OS prompt to allow java connections. Once accepted, the server starts fine.

Answer (score 19):

Try this if you tried to `restart` your service, but it still doesn't work

1. stop your service

```
brew services stop mongodb-community
```

2. restart your macOS
3. start your service again

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for cases where your launchctl daemon gets messed up and fails to start. If nothing else works, try this!

Answer (score 15):

**To see the real errors, you need to run the service without brew**

I had a similar problem, but instead of mongodb, I could not start apache(httpd).

```
$ brew services start httpd                                                                                                                                                        
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 
/Users/john/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 
5.
FAIL: 1
```

Unfortunately brew doesn't show the user what causes this error. At first I tried to use the tips from the answers in this thread, but neither reinstalling apache nor `unload -w/load -w` helped.
I also found nothing in the brew logs. I decided to investigate apache itself. To do this **I ran apache without brew**:

```
$ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.51/bin/apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 66 of /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40_3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40_3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so, 0x000A): tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40_3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libphp5.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libphp5.so' (no such file)
FAIL: 1
```

Then it was finally clear what was the reason why httpd service was not starting. It turned out that after the php upgrade, the php version had changed and I forgot to write the new php version in the apache configuration file.
I quickly fixed this and apache started up.

Comment: This is a good tip; it worked for me.

Comment: Great tip, however as a reminder for others: use this only for debugging. Brew is doing some stuff for you automatically (like setting ulimit values) so you will need to know what you are doing.

Comment: great tip to get the actual error

Answer (score 13):

I faced a similar problem with postgresql 11 and restarting the service did not help. The issue arose when my MacBook **restarted abruptly**.

After checking the ports and trying out all the possible solutions, I decided to look into the logs.

```
tail -n 100 /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@11.log
```

This gave me the last 100 lines of the log where I found this:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 479) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgresql@11"?
```

Clearly, the issue was with `postmaster.pid` so I deleted it:

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@11/postmaster.pid
```

Started the postgres service again:

```
brew services start postgresql@11
```

and voila! It worked.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the mongodb-community is already started. So do restart it instead of starting, by the following command:

```
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 6):

I had similar error in regard to `postgres`.

```
$ brew services start postgresql
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/yrk/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5.
```

I've tried restart and it looked promising:

```
$ brew services restart postgres
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
```

But there still was a problem when trying to connect:

```
 $ psql -d postgres -U apiuser
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Checking postgres log as mentioned by @mansoor.khan helped, in my case it was:
`tail /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`.

And the issue was clear:

```
$ tail /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
2022-05-19 14:18:46.029 CEST [32374] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-05-19 14:18:46.029 CEST [32374] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.3.
2022-05-19 14:18:56.071 CEST [32676] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-05-19 14:18:56.071 CEST [32676] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.3.
2022-05-19 14:19:06.111 CEST [32885] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-05-19 14:19:06.111 CEST [32885] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.3.
2022-05-19 14:19:16.128 CEST [33102] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-05-19 14:19:16.128 CEST [33102] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.3.
2022-05-19 14:19:26.166 CEST [33434] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2022-05-19 14:19:26.166 CEST [33434] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is not compatible with this version 14.3.
```

Now the problem is: how to revert to previous version or upgrade old data to new version of postgres DB, but this is for another topic.

Comment: `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` is designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

restart

I mean restart the computer.

I tried everything written here, including uninstalling and reinstalling the mongo itself. After all the struggle, restarting computer solved the problem for me, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

run something like `launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community` before the `load` command solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on mysql.

```
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/gerd/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` exited with 5.
```

In my case the mysqld miss the osx network connection permission. After restart OSX it appear the network permissions dialog. I granted the permission to msqld and the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. This commands helped me

```
brew uninstall rabbitmq
brew uninstall erlang
brew install rabbitmq
brew services restart rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this when upgrading from 4.4 to 5.0 and I suspect it’s similar for you. Lets assume you were upgrading 5.x to 6.x then the resolution would be ...

1. check your mongo log, e.g.

```
vi /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

2. Look for any errors relating to file/directory permissions and fix those, e.g. though I’m not quite sure whether ‘wheel’ or ‘admin’ is right.

```
sudo chown yourloginname:wheel thedirectory/*
```

3. Roll back to your previous working version of mongo (e.g. 5.x)
4. Start Mongo 5
5. Start a Mongo Shell and type

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0" } )
```

6. Check the logs to verify the database has detected 5.0
7. Uninstall 5.x
8. Re-install 6.x
9. Restart / start 6.x

It should now work?

Answer (score 1):

You may run into this if the service is already running, but as another user.

For example, you may have run `sudo brew services start example` and are now running `brew services info example`. It tells you it's not running and you think "hm, it should be running" and enter `brew services start example`.

Potentially `example` is already bound to, say, port 7777 and now you ask for another program to be bound to the same port, leading to a failing service start.

In short: **If you are binding to a port, check if the same service is already running as another user and bound to the same port.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, another httpd process was running on the Mac. Killed with monitor tool allowed me to start httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Happened with redis. Realized there was a `bind` setting in the config, binding the server to an incorrect ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating to macOS Ventura, after trying a lot of stuff that didn't work the problem seemed that homebrew didn't have xcode-select and had conflicts with the newly installed OS:

what solved the issue:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then update brew packages:

```
brew upgrade MySQL
```

Start MySQL as usually with homebrew

```
brew services restart MySQL
```

[Update homebrew on macos ventura](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3889)

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was linked to the fact that the `data` folder and the `log` file location did not exist.

In my case I went from an upgrade via Homebrew of an old version of Mongo to version 7. The previous folder either went AWOL or was deleted during the upgrade process.

To define the data folder and logs location:

> mongod --port 29000 --dbpath your_homedir --logpath your_homedir/mongod.log --fork

[Source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/#run-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

After trying every solution in this thread I just restarted the system and it fixed it.

Sometimes you just need some old school solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I still had the sock file after completely uninstalled it. So I removed the sock file:

```
sudo rm -f /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Then, I reinstalled it and it worked. So, probably you only need to remove the sock file and restart it.