# Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error Error: Failure while executing

Tags: python, mongodb, macos

Please help me with the solution as i am trying to install `mongodb` via `brew` on `mac M1 air`.

It is throwing me this error

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing;
/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/shrirajdesai/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2.plist
exited with 5.
```

Comment: Check the logs (probably in `/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb`) what is the problem and add here some more information so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when I tried to run `brew services restart postgresql` and I got this error:

```
 Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
 Error: Failure while executing; /bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist exited with 5.
```

**This solution worked for me:**
[brew services. Cant start service. get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70587518/10152467)

In my case I replaced the `mongodb-community` with `postgresql`. I am currently running macOS Big Sur version 11.6.2.