# brew services start mongodb-community not working on m1 mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal, homebrew

I was following mongodb docs to install `mongodb-community` on my mac. But this error appeared:

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Error: Failure while executing; /bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/lakshyadhariwal/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` exited with 5
```

I tried to do the final step of `brew services start mongodb-community`,  googling and tried various answers online but none worked.

[image: Error screen]

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975769/brew-services-cant-start-service-get-bootstrap-failed-5-input-output-error)

Comment: doesn't work , i have tried @Alok

Comment: For anyone that is searching for a solution . I ran mongodb using docker .

Comment: Check `brew services list` if mongo is running correctly and check the logs (probably in `/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb`) what is the problem.