# MySQL brew cannot run on macOS Monterey?

Tags: mysql, laravel, macos, laravel-valet, macos-monterey

MySQL suddenly stopped working after updating from macOS Big Sur to Monterey (naive). Local Laravel dev environment suddenly lost connection to MySQL. Couldn't debug it properly (still learning), so decided to do a fresh MySQL installation via brew. Was installed through brew previously as well.

On the final step, `mysql_secure_installation` shows this:

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

`brew services start mysql`

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/stranger/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` exited with 5.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why would it suddenly drop?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [brew services. Cant start service. get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975769/brew-services-cant-start-service-get-bootstrap-failed-5-input-output-error)

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but, according to the MySQL documentation, Monterey is not yet a supported platform.

[MySQL Supported Platforms](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I tried `brew uninstall mysql`, `brew install mysql` and then `brew services restart mysql` and it did the trick for me