# Brew service start not working. Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

Recently I installed mongodb-community@5.0 via home brew using this intallation link.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

But after running this command `brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`

It is showing this error:

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/502 /Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@5.0.plist` exited with 5.

The installation get successfull:

the response of `mongod --version` is

```
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.21",
    "gitVersion": "4fad44a858d8ee2d642566fc8872ef410f6534e4",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

**This is my .zshrc file**

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@5.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community@5.0/bin:$PATH"
```

**Config inside mongod.config file is:**

located at opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf (M1 chip)

```
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
  ipv6: true
```

Comment: Check the logfile `/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

Comment: There is no mongo.log file present at this location. mongodb folder is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [brew services. Cant start service. get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975769/brew-services-cant-start-service-get-bootstrap-failed-5-input-output-error)

Comment: No I tried the reddit thread as well