# Error while Trying to start mariadb service using brew

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.5, mariadb-10.1

% brew services start mariadb
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist` exited with 5.

I want just to start mariadb on my mac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [brew services. Cant start service. get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975769/brew-services-cant-start-service-get-bootstrap-failed-5-input-output-error)